# Colspan not working in my HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in which I can't use Colspan and it's doesn't work even I change it,

**This is the output I expected but in Others(Please specify)**  there's another column and I can't remove it, Can someone knows the solution?

[image]

**This is what I've tried** I put it in snippet so that we can show the actual output I've been trying

```css
    body {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 12px;
      }
     
      .container-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #cccccc;
      }
     
      .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 5%;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
     
      .print-button {
        background-color: #b2c2ce;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 500px;
      }
     
      .container-body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 50px;
      }
     
      .appendix {
        position: absolute;
        top: 65px;
        right: 50px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: italic;
      }
     
      table {
        border: 1px solid;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 40px;
      }
     
      th,
      td {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }
     
      th {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
      }
     
      .center-text {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
     
      @media print {
        .container {
          display: none;
        }
     
        .container-body {
          background-color: #f0f0f0;
          box-shadow: none;
          width: 210mm;
          height: 297mm;
        }
     
        .container h3 {
          color: transparent;
        }
     
        .container-wrapper {
          align-items: flex-start;
        }
     
        table {
          margin-top: 15px;
        }
     
        .appendix {
          top: 10px;
        }
     
        /* Adjust font size for Disbursement Voucher in print */
        .center-text b {
          font-size: 14px;
        }
      }
     .innerTable{
       margin:0px;
       border-color:white;  
     }
     .lastRow{
       padding:0px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h3></h3>
        <button class="print-button" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container-body">
        <span class="appendix">Appendix 32</span>
        <table>
        <thead>
    
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="5" rowspan="4" class="center-text">Department of Social Welfare and Development <br> Capitol Site, Butuan City  <br> <br> <br> <br><b>DISBURSEMENT VOUCHER</b></td>
            <td><b> Fund Cluster : <br>Cluster O1 </b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
    
            <td><b>Date : </b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#c6e0b4; border:1.8px solid;"><b> DV No. : </b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="lastRow">
                <table class="innerTable">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Mode of <br> Payment</b></td>
                    <td>
                    <span style="margin-right: 20px;"></span> 
                    <input type="checkbox"> MDS Check 
                    <span style="margin-right: 20px;"></span>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Commercial Check 
                    <span style="margin-right: 20px;"></span>
                    <input type="checkbox"> ADA
                    <span style="margin-right: 20px;"></span> 
                    <input type="checkbox"> Others (Please specify) _______
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="50" height="30" colspan="1"> <b>Payee</b></td>
            <td width="150" colspan="3" style="font-size: 14px;"><b>LBP</b></td>
            <td style="font-size: 10px;" width="170">TIN/Employee No.:</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width="50" rowspan="2" height="30" colspan="1"> <b>Address</b></td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="font-size: 14px;"><b>DSWD, CAPITOL SITE, BUTUAN CITY</b></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" class="lastRow">
                <table class="innerTable">
                <tr><td><b>Initiator:</b></td></tr>
                <tr><td><br></td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
                
                <td colspan="1" >Particulars</td>
                <td colspan="1">Responsibility Center</td>
                <td colspan="1">Responsibility Center</td>
                <td >Amount</td>
            
            
            </tr>

            
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't have a tabular data structure there. You don't even have a tabular *layout*. Stop trying to abusing the table element for layout. [We have Grid now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids).

Comment: `colspan="5"` serves to make a cell on one row *span the combined width* of **5 existing cells** on another row (below / above it). The "existing" part is very important, because you have no rows anywhere with 5 cells. The most you have is 2 cells, so it will behave as if you used `"colspan="2"`. The same rule applies for `rowspan` and actual cells in other columns that overlap with it. Things can actually get quite complicated if you try to combine the two settings, I would not recommend doing so, especially not if you don't know much about what they when used on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The colspan attribute in HTML specifies the number of columns a cell should span.**

you should set td colspans so that in each **tr** sum of colspans equals to table columns.

```css
  

.container-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #cccccc;
  }
 
  .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
 
  .print-button {
    background-color: #b2c2ce;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 500px;
  }
 
  .container-body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px;
  }
 
  .appendix {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    right: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
  }
 
  table {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
 
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
 
  th {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
 
  .center-text {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
 
  @media print {
    .container {
      display: none;
    }
 
    .container-body {
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      box-shadow: none;
      width: 210mm;
      height: 297mm;
    }
 
    .container h3 {
      color: transparent;
    }
 
    .container-wrapper {
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
 
    table {
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
 
    .appendix {
      top: 10px;
    }
 
    /* Adjust font size for Disbursement Voucher in print */
    .center-text b {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }
 .innerTable{
   margin:0px;
   border-color:white;  
 }
 .lastRow{
   padding:0px;
 }
```

```html
   <div class="container-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <h3></h3>
        <button class="print-button" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
      </div>
      <div class="container-body">
        <span class="appendix">Appendix 32</span>
        <table>
          <thead></thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="5" rowspan="4" class="center-text">Department of Social Welfare and Development <br> Capitol Site, Butuan City <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <b>DISBURSEMENT VOUCHER</b>
              </td>
              <td>
                <b> Fund Cluster : <br>Cluster O1 </b>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <b>Date : </b>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="background-color:#c6e0b4; border:1.8px solid;">
                <b> DV No. : </b>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <b>Mode of <br> Payment </b>
              </td>
              <td colspan="5">
                <span style="margin-right: 20px;"></span>
                <input type="checkbox"> MDS Check <span style="margin-right: 20px;"></span>
                <input type="checkbox"> Commercial Check <span style="margin-right: 20px;"></span>
                <input type="checkbox"> ADA <span style="margin-right: 20px;"></span>
                <input type="checkbox"> Others (Please specify) _______            
              </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
              <td width="50" height="30">
                <b>Payee</b>
              </td>
              <td width="150" colspan="2" style="font-size: 14px;">
                <b>LBP</b>
              </td>
              <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 10px;" width="170">TIN/Employee No.:</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="50" rowspan="2" height="30" colspan="1">
                <b>Address</b>
              </td>
              <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="font-size: 14px;">
                <b>DSWD, CAPITOL SITE, BUTUAN CITY</b>
              </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="lastRow">
                <b>Initiator:</b>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">Particulars</td>
              <td colspan="1">Responsibility Center</td>
              <td colspan="1">Responsibility Center</td>
              <td>Amount</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <b>Travel Reim bursement for test</b>
                <br/>
                <b>Test</b>
                <br/>
                <b>Test</b>
              </td>
              <td rowspan="2">
              </td>
              <td rowspan="2">
              </td>
              <td>
                Php -
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                Amount Due
              </td>
              <td>
                Php -
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have updated snippet above I tried that it works, but in second phase I have problem under Initiator , I tried rowspan but it didn't work

Comment: What do you want the table to look like? Please share the desired image so that I can help you more precisely

Comment: Actuall this is the image that I wanted [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsuvp.png), still til now , I'm trying to achieve this all But I've encountered some problem I think because of the columns, I've updated my snippet above

Comment: I updated my code snippet, check it. I hope that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```css
        body {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .container-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #cccccc;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 5%;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding: 0 10px;
        }

        .print-button {
            background-color: #b2c2ce;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 500px;
        }

        .container-body {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .appendix {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            right: 20px;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        table {
            border: 2px solid;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 40px;
        }

        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        .center-text {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        @media print {
            .container {
                display: none;
            }
            
            .container-body {
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                box-shadow: none;
                width: 210mm;
                height: 297mm;
            }
            
            .container h3 {
                color: transparent;
            }
            
            .container-wrapper {
                align-items: flex-start;
            }
            table {
                margin-top: 15px;
            }
            .appendix {
                top: 10px;
            }

            /* Adjust font size for Disbursement Voucher in print */
            .center-text b {
                font-size: 14px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <h3></h3>
            <button class="print-button" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
        </div>

        <div class="container-body">
            <span class="appendix">Appendix 32</span>
            <table>
                <thead>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>

                    <td colspan="5" rowspan="4" class="center-text">xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx <br> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <br> <br> <br>  <br><b>DISBURSEMENT VOUCHER</b></td> 
                    <td width="150"><b> Fund Cluster : <br>Cluster O1 </b></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    
                    <td ><b>Date : December 1, 2023</b></td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b> TT No. : 23-08-0001</b></td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>   
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td width="50"> <b>Mode of <br> Payment</b></td>
                    <td colspan="5"> <input type="checkbox"> MDS Check <input type="checkbox"> Commercial Check <input type="checkbox"> ADA <input type="checkbox"> Others (Please specify) _______</td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's different the " MDS Check  Commercial Check  ADA  Others (Please specify)" must not align in Fund Cluster : Cluster O1 Above :(

Comment: Please try again my code. I updated something. If you specify the width on `td` element, you will get what you wanted. https://pasteboard.co/s9a9sh3xhVAD.png

Comment: I have updated snippet above it works, but in second phase I have problem under Initiator , I tried rowspan but it didn't work

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza What's the initiator? I can't see what do you wanna do with rowspan. Show me your desired result with screenshot.

Comment: I have screenshot above, the text is the initiator

Comment: I saw Initiator text on your bottom of screenshot image. Do you want to make full table as per your screeshot?.

Comment: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsuvp.png) Actually this is what I wanted but I tried to make them one by one and Im stack in Initiator text

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza Can you share me current code so that I can fix your issue? You can  post a new question over here.

Answer (score 0):

You have set 6 cells in the first row, so you have to match the cell count in the last row with the first row. You can insert a table in the last row to meet your requirement. Unfortunately, the preview in below cannot show the layout correctly.

This is my solution.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.container-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.print-button {
  background-color: #b2c2ce;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 500px;
}

.container-body {
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.appendix {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.center-text {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

@media print {
  .container {
    display: none;
  }
  .container-body {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
  .container h3 {
    color: transparent;
  }
  .container-wrapper {
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  table {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .appendix {
    top: 10px;
  }
  /* Adjust font size for Disbursement Voucher in print */
  .center-text b {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

.innerTable {
  border-style: none ;
  margin: 0px;
  width:100%;
}

.lastRow {  
  padding: 0px;  
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-wrapper">
   <div class="container">
     <h3></h3>
     <button class="print-button" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
   </div>

   <div class="container-body">
     <span class="appendix">Appendix 32</span>
     <table>
       <thead>

       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="5" rowspan="4" class="center-text">xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx <br> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <br> <br> <br> <br><b>DISBURSEMENT VOUCHER</b></td>
           <td><b> Fund Cluster : <br>Cluster O1 </b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>

           <td><b>Date : December 1, 2023</b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><b> TT No. : 23-08-0001</b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="6" class="lastRow">
             <table class="innerTable">
               <tr>
                 <td><b>Mode of <br> Payment</b></td>
                 <td>
                   <input type="checkbox"> MDS Check <input type="checkbox"> Commercial Check <input type="checkbox"> ADA <input type="checkbox"> Others (Please specify) _______
                 </td>
               </tr>
             </table>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td width="50" height="30" colspan="1"> <b>Payee</b></td>
           <td width="150" colspan="3" style="font-size: 14px;"><b>LBP</b></td>
           <td style="font-size: 10px;" width="170">TIN/Employee No.:</td>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td width="50" rowspan="2" height="30" colspan="1"> <b>Address</b></td>
           <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="font-size: 14px;"><b>DSWD, CAPITOL SITE, BUTUAN CITY</b></td>
           <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" class="lastRow">
             <table class="innerTable">
               <tr><td><b>Initiator:</b></td></tr>
               <tr><td><br></td></tr>
             </table>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I attached the jsFiddle link for your reference.

https://jsfiddle.net/xw817azs/

Comment: I have updated snippet above it works, but in second phase I have problem under Initiator , I tried rowspan but it didn't work

Comment: I have screenshot above, the text is the initiator

Comment: I have updated the code and link, you may check now.

Answer (score -1):

In the code you provided, you have a table row where you want to merge cells using colspan. However, the issue may arise from the fact that you are using both colspan and rowspan attributes on the same td element. This combination can sometimes lead to unexpected layout results.
Modify the code to achieve the desired output. Since you want to merge the cells in the first column (spanning both rows), you can remove the rowspan attribute from that cell and keep only the colspan attribute. Here's the modified code:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="center-text">xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx <br> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <br> <br> <br>  <br><b>DISBURSEMENT VOUCHER</b></td> 
    <td><b> Fund Cluster : <br>Cluster O1 </b></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td> <!-- Empty cell for colspan -->
    <td colspan="4"><b>Mode of <br> Payment</b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox"> MDS Check <input type="checkbox"> Commercial Check <input type="checkbox"> ADA <input type="checkbox"> Others (Please specify) _______</td>
</tr> 

By removing the rowspan attribute from the first cell in the first row and adjusting the colspan values in the second row, you should be able to achieve the desired table layout.
```

Comment: That won't work. Removing the `rowspan` from the first cell would stop the first cell from spaning the rows containing the fund code, the date, the string starting DV, and the empty cell.

Comment: @Quentin I have updated snippet above it works, but in second phase I have problem under Initiator , I tried rowspan but it didn't work

Comment: I have screenshot above, the text is the initiator

Comment: @marivicvaldehueza — You didn’t do what I recommended so why are you @-ing me? You didn’t do what this answer recommended so why are you doing it here?